# .Net Core Hangfire - Increase worker count

Tags: parallel-processing, .net-core, worker, hangfire

I have a .Net Core application with Hangfire implementation.

There is a recurring job per minute as below:-

```
RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate<IS2SScheduledJobs>(x => x.ProcessInput(), Cron.MinuteInterval(1));

var hangfireOptions = new BackgroundJobServerOptions
            {
                WorkerCount = 20,
            };
            _server = new BackgroundJobServer(hangfireOptions);
```

The ProcessInput() internally checks the BlockingCollection() of some Ids to process, it keeps on continuously processing.

There is a time when the first ten ProcessInput() jobs keeps on processing with 10 workers where as the other new ProcessInput() jobs gets enqueued.

For this purpose, I wanted to increase the workers count, say around 50, so that there would be 50 ProcessInput() jobs being processed parallely.

Please suggest.
Thanks.

Comment: By default, the number of threads (workers) it uses is 5 per Processor Count. With a maximum of 20.

Answer (score 13):

In the .NET Core version you can set the worker count when adding the Hangfire Server:

```
services.AddHangfireServer(options => options.WorkerCount = 50);
```

Answer (score -1):

you can try increasing the worker process using this method. You have to know the number of processors running on your servers. To get 100 workers, you can try

```
var options = new BackgroundJobServerOptions { WorkerCount = Environment.ProcessorCount * 25 };
app.UseHangfireServer(options);
```

[Source](http://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/background-processing/configuring-degree-of-parallelism.html)